# google_maps plugin rjs problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

So I am using bhedana's google_maps plugin and have built a search for points that load on page render.  I have all my points refreshing with

```
page.replace_html 'locations', :partial => 'locations'
```

but when I include

```
page.replace_html 'map', :partial => 'map'
```

in the same rjs file and have a partial that looks like

```
<%= @map.to_html %>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 350px;">
    <%= @map.div %>
</div>
```

The map fails to appear when I submit.  Anyone have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it worked out.  Lots of code...